# Can I install Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Can anyone suggest if it is possible to install VS 2015 on my dev machine?

It should not disturb the existing VS 2010 and VS 2013 versions.

Comment: Why not, make sure that in your `PATH` variable everything written as it should be

Comment: Put it into a VM - that's the safest way to go. Or use the ready-made VM's up on Azure to play around with it

Comment: Have you seen this? (Doesn't relate to VS2010 though) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27991461/it-is-safe-to-install-visual-studio-2015-preview-side-by-side-to-visual-studio-2

Comment: It works fine. No need to run in a VM. It is very close to being releaseable.